# Xamarin forms app for Android crashes with Dotfuscator community edition enabled

Tags: android, xamarin, dotfuscator

My Xamarin Forms app crashes on startup in release mode with Dotfuscator Community Edition enabled but works fine in debug mode or release mode with Dotfuscator disabled.

From the documentation, I can see that I might need renaming exclusions but it doesn't give any information about how to identify exclusions I might need. I tried excluding the namespaces for all modules that use reflection but that didn't help.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should do next?

Update:

The application crashes before displaying the splash screen. Following SushiHangover's suggestion, I used the Device Log option in Visual Studio to capture the log while I launched the app.

There are various errors and warnings in the system log, but the first error seems to be this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.scenesteeler/crc64cc08be371a3c8589.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.scenesteeler:layout/abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode: Binary XML file line #23 in com.scenesteeler:layout/abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsFrameLayout 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3807)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at ... (removed the rest of the error stack report)
```

It seems to me that the application crashes before getting to any of my code. It looks like running Dotfuscator has somehow corrupted the package.

Comment: Review `logcat` for which method(s) are failing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks both! I don't have any specific code I can point to yet. I will use logcat to see if I can identify what is failing. I am new to developing for Android so I am feeling my way on this at the moment.

Comment: Hi @JessieZhang-MSFT - Thanks for your interest :-) ! I have updated the post with information from the system log on the Android device. I have made some minor updates to the app, and it still works fine without Dotfuscator enabled, and crashes on startup with it enabled. Any suggestions for next steps would be welcome, but it does look like a Dotfuscator issue rather than a Xamarin or .NET issue.